# Why do nUnit tests frequently disappear in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm running into a frustrating issue with nUnit 3. I believe this issue was also happening with nUnit 2, but it's happening more frequently now.

In VS2015 upon compiling I will suddenly lose half of my unit tests in the Test Explorer after a build. A clean build or visual studio restart will fix it, but that's really annoying in a large solution. I haven't determined why some tests continue to show up and others disappear - a comparison of the project files show they are using the identical libraries and project settings.

I am using nUnit3 with the nUnit3 test adapter installed as an extension as well as the nuget package (tried nuget package only, tests don't show up)

Comment: Very likely to be a bug in the adapter. Other test frameworks work fine.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that? I'm also struggling with this annoying bug.

Comment: I'm glad to hear I'm not the only one suffering from this issue. I'm using NUnit 2.6 on VS 2015 through the NuGet extension. I'm curious whether this would be a VS bug, or an NUnit one, so we could bark up the right tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular issue was fixed in adapter version 3.0.9. See issues [126](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/126) and [131](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/131).

The casue, from Charlie Poole:

> I discovered that we were getting a COM exception from VS when calling
>   RecordEnd on Explicit Tests for which no RecordStart was called. This
>   does not seem to actually cause a problem for earlier VS products but
>   appears to do so for VS2015. I'm catching the exception and displaying
>   a message. This seems to eliminate the intermittent failures of VS2015
>   to complete the execution of tests but I'm not certain the problem
>   won't pop up again.
>
> In any case, it still seems like a good idea that we don't propogate
>   exceptions back to NUnit from the listener.

Comment: For reference purposes, I'll link the discussion on the adapter for NUnit 2.x: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-vs-adapter/issues/110